# How to close InfoWindow when clicking on another marker when multiple markers are displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to close the current infowindow when I click on any next marker, for now it shows all infowindows after clicking.

**My JavaScript**

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: latlng,
    draggable: false,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    map: map,
    icon: 'a.png',
    labelContent: '<?php echo $rating.' % Review '.$review;?>',
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
    labelClass: "labels"
});

marker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<p><?php echo $name ;?></p>'
});


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
});
```

Comment: If you only ever want one infowindow open, only create one, move it to each clicked marker.  Possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save previously opened infowindow in a variable and then close when a new window opens.

```
var currWindow =false; 

base.attachInfo = function(marker, i){
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Content"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        if( currWindow ) {
           currWindow.close();
        }

        currWindow = infowindow;
        infowindow.open(base.map, marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Rather than doing that, I suggest you look at @geocodezip comment on your question.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why someone downvoted it before, this is the correct answer! I have been trying to do this for the last 2 hours (waste of time), solved now thanks to your answer!